# c++ std::vector iterator constructor with first == last

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have a function which needs to divide a vector up into n sub-vectors.
For example, it might look something like this:

```
void foo(std::vector<uint8_t> vec, int numSubVectors){
    size_t size = vec.size() / numSubVectors;
    auto iter = vec.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < numSubVectors; ++i) {
        auto sub_vec = std::vector<uint8_t>(iter, iter + size);
        // do something with sub_vec
        // ...

        iter += size;
    }
}
```

I need this to work when called with `foo({}, 1)`, where sub_vec gets assigned an empty vector on the first (and only) iteration of the loop.
I'm concerned about the `std::vector<uint8_t>(iter, iter + size)`. Does the c++ standard allow a vector to be constructed using its range constructor when first == last?

According to [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), "The range used is [first,last), which includes all the elements between first and last, including the element pointed by first but not the element pointed by last", but that statement doesn't make any sense when first == last?

I tried running it on an online IDE and it seems to work (https://ideone.com/V9hylA), so it's clearly not prohibited, but is it undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [iterator.requirements.general](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#9) of the standard:

> An iterator and a sentinel denoting a range are comparable. A range [i, s) is empty if i == s; otherwise [...]

So when first == last, the standard explicitly defines this as an empty range.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've updated the text for my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The iterator pair `[first, last)` where `first == last` is how we define an empty range. It's syntactically and logically valid. Constructing a `std::vector` from that iterator pair will do the correct thing and create an empty container.

Comment: can you provide a source for this? preferably something from the standard.
I know from a mathematics perspective, [a, a) is the empty set, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything with respect to c++.

Comment: @DanielMcIntosh What I've found so far is [vector.cons](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector.cons). Where N is the distance between first and last (or 0 in the case of an empty range). It makes 0 calls to the copy constructor.

Comment: @DanielMcIntosh Or [sequence.reqmts](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts), [Table 66](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#tab:container.seq.req) "*Ensures:* distance(begin(), end()) == distance(i, j)". I interpret as the resulting container size will be 0 when given an empty range. Note that I'm not a standard expert.